# crosstab dynamic in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot

this is output from query true like this:

```
bln bt  cl  kj  ma  pj  sb  sn  st  wh
1   421 465 437 474 196 29  146 392 37
2   398 443 328 462 181 0   30  438 0
3   209 258 105 298 51  0   0   213 0
```

The output above from query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 8192;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'max(case when cabang = ''',
cabang,
''' then jum else 0 end) AS ',
cabang
)
) INTO @sql
FROM pkbtotal_;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bln, ', @sql, '
FROM pkbtotal_
GROUP BY bln');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The output above is true where the vertical is month and horizontal is branch with 1 as jan, 2 as feb, and 3 as march, but when I change crosstab like branch in vertical and month at horizontal like this, I am get error:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 8192;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'max(case when bln = ''',
bln,
''' then jum else 0 end) AS ',
bln
)
) INTO @sql
FROM pkbtotal_;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT cabang, ', @sql, '
FROM pkbtotal_
GROUP BY cabang');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am getting error:

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT cabang, ', @sql, '
FROM pkbtotal_
GROUP BY cabang')

> OK
>   Time: 0,238s

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,max(case when bln = '2' then jum else 0 end) AS 2,max(case when bln = '3' then' at line 1
>   Time: 0,24s

How to make branch in vertical and month at horisontal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Stored Proc to dynamically generate, then run, a pivot from your specifications:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot